# What's the button on the left corner of a XFCE4 window

Tags: xfce, window, button, window-buttons

I'm using xfce4 and my theme is [orchis-dark](https://www.xfce-look.org/p/1357889/). I was always wondering about a select button on the left corner of my window.

You can see the button in the following screenshots:

[image: Window title bar]

[image: Window title bar pressed]

What does it do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure, because you are using a non-default theme, but chances are that this is the *Stick* button.

What this button does is that it makes the window "sticky" so it would appear on all workspaces.

You can make sure that this is the case by opening Settings Manager → *Window Manager* → *Style* tab and hover over this button in the *Button layout* section. You should get a tooltip as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: XFCE Window Manager]

Also have a look at this [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) question from which I got the above image: [What is “stick” button on windows in xfce?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333013/what-is-stick-button-on-windows-in-xfce)

**Sidenote:** you can also hide and rearrange the position of the buttons in your windows title bar by dragging and dropping them in the respective frames of the *Button layout* section.